# ACF: Obtain data from repeater which is in nested group

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to obtain data from a `repeater` but I'm getting an `Array to string conversion` error, unsure why.

My `repeater` is nested within two `groups`. Here is the ACF backend for reference:

`welcome_screen` is the parent `group`

[image]

`terms_for_the_survey` is the child `group`

[image]

Within the `terms_for_the_survey` group, you can see the repeater called `terms_listing`. This `repeater` just has a `text` option, see below:

[image]

Now, I'm simply trying to create a `ul` list of the items in the `repeater`. Here is what I've tried:

```html
<?php

  $welcome_screen = get_field('welcome_screen'); // parent group

  if ($welcome_screen):
    $title        = $welcome_screen['title'];
    $standfirst   = $welcome_screen['standfirst'];

    $terms_group    = $welcome_screen['terms_for_the_survey']; // child group
    $terms_text     = $terms_group['terms_text'];
    $terms_repeater = $terms_group['terms_listing'];

    // var_dump($terms_repeater);

  endif;

?>


<div class="screen">
  <p><?php echo $terms_text; ?></p>

  <?php if( have_rows($terms_repeater) ) : ?>
    <ul>
      <?php while( have_rows($terms_repeater) ) : the_row();
        $text = get_sub_field('terms'); ?>

        <li><?php echo $text; ?></li>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

But, as mentioned, I get an `Array to string conversion` error, what looks to be on the line: `<?php if( have_rows($terms_repeater) ) : ?>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

have_rows($terms_repeater) return string or bool this is not array and you have

> Array to string conversion

Check what returns $terms_repeater and have_rows($terms_repeater)

Example :

```
<div class="screen">
  <p><?php echo $terms_text; ?></p>
<?php 
  var_dump($terms_repeater);
  var_dump(have_rows($terms_repeater));
?>
  <?php if( have_rows($terms_repeater) ) : ?>
    <ul>
      <?php while( have_rows($terms_repeater) ) : the_row();
        $text = get_sub_field('terms'); ?>

        <li><?php echo $text; ?></li>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, a `var_dump($terms_repeater);` returns an array with the values of the repeater, so it prints an array of the text values in the repeater. Doing `var_dump(have_rows($terms_repeater));` returns the `Array to string conversion` error